# In SwiftUI Picker expands to occupy entire space inside a HStack

Tags: text, swiftui, picker, hstack

I have a Text and Picker in HStack separated by Spacer. What I want is that the Spacer should should occupy maximum space between picker and text so that the Text and Picker are not the extreme ends of the HStack but, the picker expands to occupy maximum space. Any clue as to how can this can achieved and that the size of Picker is equivalent to its content?

```
HStack() {
                Text(template.name)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Spacer()
                if template.oneItemOnly == "1" {
                    if let items = template.items {
                        Picker(selection: $selectedSegment, label:Text("")){
                            ForEach( 0..<items.count) { index in
                                Text(items[index].name)
                                    .tag(index)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Answer (score 3):

You can set max width of `Spacer` by adding a `.frame` modifier:

```
Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Alternatively you can try using `GeometryReader` to set the width of the `Picker` relative to the screen width:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    ...
    Picker(selection: $selectedSegment, label: EmptyView()) {
        ...
    }
    .frame(width: proxy.size.width / 3)
}
```

You may also try to implement your own Picker like presented here: [Custom Segmented Picker](https://gist.github.com/frankfka/2784adff55be72a4f044d8c2bcc9fd3f)

Comment: This causes the Spacer and Picker to occupy equal width.

Comment: @Rakesh.P You may try using `GeometryReader` in this case.